# cannot load the model in Azure ML

Tags: azure, machine-learning, keras, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

when I try to load a model in Azure ML with below code I get an error.
anyone know how to fix the issue with Azure?

```
from tensorflow import keras
keras.models.load_model('model.h5')
```

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [24], in <cell line: 2>()
          1 from tensorflow import keras
    ----> 2 keras.models.load_model('model_base-3.h5')
    
    File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/save.py:184, in load_model(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
        181 with generic_utils.CustomObjectScope(custom_objects or {}):
        182   if (h5py is not None and (
        183       isinstance(filepath, h5py.File) or h5py.is_hdf5(filepath))):
    --> 184     return hdf5_format.load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
        186   if sys.version_info >= (3, 4) and isinstance(filepath, pathlib.Path):
        187     filepath = str(filepath)
    
    File /anaconda/envs/azureml_py38/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py:176, in load_model_from_hdf5(filepath, custom_objects, compile)
        174 if model_config is None:
        175   raise ValueError('No model found in config file.')
    --> 176 model_config = json.loads(model_config.decode('utf-8'))
        177 model = model_config_lib.model_from_config(model_config,
        178                                            custom_objects=custom_objects)
        180 # set weights
    
    AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Answer (score 0):

When we are calling the model we first need to consider **tensorflow** library and before that **OS** library.

```
import os

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
```

In the given question, **tensorflow** was not called and even if it was imported, to load the H5 model, we need to use **tensorflow**. Replace the existing code block of loading with the below code block.

```
import os

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

tf.keras.models.load_model(filepath, custom_objects=None, compile=True)
```

this is the procedure to call the model to solve the current issue.

Comment: still does not work. can you please specify how you save the model in the first place? is that the right way? model_name.save('./outputs/model/model.h5')

Comment: Yes, it is the right way to use.